# why there is an index.php file in all frameworks?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, laravel

When I used codeigniter there was an 'index.php' that comes in url and I had to remove it using htaccess rewrite rule(for a beginner and  for one who has no knowledge about htaccess or its rewrite rule-it was difficult to remove it for the first time to make url pretty)

I thought it was a codeigniter nuisance and decided to ignore it.

Now I m planning to start a laravel project and the same index.php comes here also.Well now I know how to handle it though

I can understand now that it is a common framework feature,but what i dont understand is its role in a framework?

Googled it but couldn,t find an answer.Please advice me and thank you in advance

Comment: please read about web servers(apache, IIS ets ) working.

Comment: basically its used to access all the system ,libraries and other folder via index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most frameworks rely on index.php to be launch the bootstrap / be the common "entrance" into the code for all requests. The .htaccess file is setup to send all unknown paths (404s) to index.php so requests to "pretty" urls that don't really exist on the file system are actually received by index.php. The framework then looks at the original requested path and compares it with a list of known routes to figure out what to do.

In general, you should not need to touch index.php or the .htaccess file. I would check the documentation of your framework of choice to find how to add routes and controllers.

Comment: but they are not unknown paths.every single page url has index.php in it and in htaccess also we are specifying it should pass through index.php even if it is not given. right??

Comment: There should only be one index.php located at the root of your application, and all other page urls are "virtual" paths that don't exist on the file system. Here is the specific information for codeignitor http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: ok.thanks for your support.let me do some research on this..

Answer (score 0):

Apache and IIS have a set of files they search for if the browser request is not sending a file name. So if the Url ends with a slash, the server actually tries to deliver (by default) index.htm, index.html or index.php, whichever he finds first. This is like a predefined rewrite rule, akthough much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

`index.php , index.html, index.*`  are the default document for most of the web servers. So you make a `index.php` in a root folder then in url you don't want to specify document name example http://www.example.com here is I'm not specifying document name by default web server tries to find `index` file if it is php then it would be `index.php`. Although you can change this default settings in apache2 using `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` this file. (I don't use IIS so I don't know how but it is possible there too)

And all framework uses this index.php for loading all classes and routing according to url request. Especially in Code-igniter, `index.php` takes  requested `url` using .htacess file to `index.php` . For example http://www.example.com/doc/1 , here this `/doc/1` part will send to `index.php` file and then this file will decide which document to load (Controller). Reading [MVC](http://salopek.eu/content/28/create-a-simple-php-mvc-framework) from scratch [tutorials](http://www.scoop.it/t/own-mvc-tutorial-in-php) will help you to understand this.

Comment: so the /doc/1 part will be loaded by index.php file ??

Comment: `index.php` file will load other classes like `CI_Router`, If you look into `index.php` and and files inside `system` folder will give you idea. Code-igniter forum is another good reference. But you just want developer a app. No need of spending time on this.